# Infinite log in loop

Tags: greeter

I guess my elementary OS system is crash. =( After boot up, log in page background is blank. After key in password, it is a infinite loop of log in page, unable to log into desktop. Any help please? Don't wish to re-install system, as that was my first time to dual boot elementary OS/Linux, would like to keep it hassle free.

Comment: I have similar problem http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/repair-the-eos-login