# Repair the elementary OS Login

Tags: wingpanel, greeter

I try to install global menu on my elementary OS from this tutorial [This tutorial](https://launchpad.net/~varlesh-l/+archive/ubuntu/test) from Reddit and due to unmet dependencies I run:

```
INSTALL:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:varlesh-l/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall wingpanel indicator-appmenu
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.wingpanel blacklist "['']"
killall wingpanel
```

But I didn't liked it so I ran the uninstaller:

```
sudo apt-get purge wingpanel indicator-appmenu
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:varlesh-l/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall pantheon-shell wingpanel
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.wingpanel blacklist "['libappmenu.so']"
killall wingpanel
```

Now I don't know what happened and I rebooted my PC.

As a result now I am not able to use elementary OS. Every time I start elementary OS it shows the login screen but after logging in nothing changes, it just continues to show the wallpaper from the login screen.

Now when I get to the login screen and proceed with `Alt+Ctrl+F1` to the terminal. I have tried some steps and but none of them worked :/

Now I'm totally stuck. Last night I tried reinstalling lightdm again and run `service lightdm restart` but nothing happend, tried [this tutorioal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/563562/how-do-i-restore-missing-launchbar-and-menubar-in-unity/564333#564333)
and got this:

```
 dconf-warning: failed to commit changes to dconf: Cannot autolaunch D-BUS without x11 $DISPLAY
```

I am using it with Windows 10 dual boot. I don't want to reinstall my elementary OS.

**UPDATE**

I got access from my windows to `.xsession-errors` and `.xsession-errors.old` with help from this [Link](https://gist.github.com/Revod/cad3bc11f4d245d20d84)

I checked the log folder (through my windows) and looked at `x-0-greeter.log` [Link](https://gist.github.com/Revod/b17e831653f269e22705)

(I think this is the critical error)

here my `Xorg.0.log` [Link](https://gist.github.com/Revod/f8c31fefb12ea5c37131)

and my lightdm.log [Link](https://gist.github.com/Revod/1858c35bf059da9865a5)

I have already tried some posts here with about the same issue, but mien couldn't be solved that way.

Comment: have you checked my answer

Answer (score 3):

Try running

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:varlesh-l/test
sudo apt-get install --reinstall elementary-desktop
```

to remove the PPA and reinstall the desktop and remove any customizations